# usage of "mbstring.script_encoding" config

Tags: php, mbstring

What is the usage of "mbstring.script_encoding" config? Is it diffrent from  mbstring.internal_encoding?

http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

It is `zend.script_encoding` now. Let me show you an example.

I have a script written in CP1251.

```
// script encoded as ANSI. var_dump() says false
var_dump(mb_check_encoding('Кириллица', 'UTF-8'));

$input = $_GET['internalInput'];
var_dump(mb_check_encoding($input, 'UTF-8'));
```

In my INIes I already have the config:

```
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

### Script test

```
bool(false) 
bool(true)
```

Where `$input` is a Cyrillic string `%D0%F3%F1%F1%EA%E8%E9`.

---

Now let us change configuration for script encoding. In `php.ini` (or in another INIes. It depends on your sys config) you can find lines like

```
; If enabled, scripts may be written in encodings that are incompatible with
; the scanner.  CP936, Big5, CP949 and Shift_JIS are the examples of such
; encodings.  To use this feature, mbstring extension must be enabled.
; Default: Off
zend.multibyte = On

; Allows to set the default encoding for the scripts.  This value will be used
; unless "declare(encoding=...)" directive appears at the top of the script.
; Only affects if zend.multibyte is set.
; Default: ""
zend.script_encoding = CP1251
```

By default all these lines are commented. Here I set `multibyte` to `On` and script encoding to `CP1251`. Do a test again.

### Script test

```
bool(true) 
bool(true)
```

---

So... we just easily migrated to UTF-8 :)

Comment: Thanks, But can you please explain it a little more

Comment: @nkamm, I cannot replicate your behavior. The first script test gives me `bool(true)`. This answer is very unclear: So you added zend.multibyte = On and zend.script_encoding = CP1251 and it migrated to UTF-8? Why?